# conditional distribution of two Poisson variates

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

$y_1 \sim  \operatorname{Po}(e^\lambda), y_2 \sim  \operatorname{Po}(e^{\lambda + \psi})$ (they are independent) I want to show that the distribution $y_2| y_1 + y_2 = u$ has distribution
 $\operatorname{Bin}(  u,e^\psi/1+e^\psi)$. I am not getting there. Here is my attempt

$$
\begin{split}
f( y_2 = v | y_1 + y_2 = u )
  &= \frac{f(y_2 =v , y_1  = u-v)}{f(y_1 + y_2 = u)}\\
  &= \frac{e^{-e^{(\lambda + \psi)}}  \frac{(e^{\lambda  + \psi})^v}{v!} e^{-e^{\lambda}} \frac{(e^\lambda)^{u-v}}{(u-v)!}}{ e^{-(e^{\lambda +\psi} + e^\lambda)}  \dfrac{(e^{\lambda + \psi}  + e^\lambda)^u}{u!}  }\\
  &=  \frac{u!}{v!(u-v!)} \frac{ (e^{\lambda + \psi })^v  }{(e^{\psi} + 1)^u (e^{\lambda})^v}
\end{split}
$$

Comment: You are already there. You do not see it yet because you do not know how to simplify it. Write down the target pmf and compare them.

Comment: thanks  @BMG so stupid of me